# Getting NoClassDefFoundError in Configjar execution when building OSB project using ANT

Tags: osb

I am changing my OSB 11g project build process to use configjar tools instead of ANT argument lines. This I am doing to make the build at individual resource level instead of project level.
I have created settings file and build.xml for the same and trying to build the project. Also, I have set the environment variables using osb_env.sh file in the server classpath. 
Still I am getting error with some logger class for which I have done no changes in the files.

Please see error below:

```
clean:

copylibs:

createSbConfigJar:
     [echo] OSB project config creation started
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] de:osb-services ......................... SUCCESS [1.000s]
[INFO] de.osb-services:base64 .................. SUCCESS [3.459s]
[INFO] de.osb-services:logging-common .......... SUCCESS [0.699s]
[INFO] de.osb-services:logging ................. SUCCESS [2.884s]
[INFO] de.osb-services:loggingOutbound ......... SUCCESS [1.396s]
[INFO] de.osb-services:monitoring .............. SUCCESS [1.038s]
[INFO] de.osb-services:build ................... FAILURE [0.572s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.546s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jun 12 12:42:49 CEST 2019
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/249M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (deploy) on project build: An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[ERROR] /pkg/vddi9/home/oradi9/jenkins/jenkins-data/workspace/OSB-R19.9_dev_test_7/build/build.xml:38: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/i18n/logging/NonCatalogLogger: weblogic.i18n.logging.NonCatalogLogger
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (deploy) on project build: An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/pkg/vddi9/home/oradi9/jenkins/jenkins-data/workspace/OSB-R19.9_dev_test_7/build/build.xml:38: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/i18n/logging/NonCatalogLogger
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/pkg/vddi9/home/oradi9/jenkins/jenkins-data/workspace/OSB-R19.9_dev_test_7/build/build.xml:38: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/i18n/logging/NonCatalogLogger
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AbstractAntMojo.executeTasks(AbstractAntMojo.java:131)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:98)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
```

Can you please tell what can be the issue here?
Please see below the existing (working) build.xml and changed(non-working) build.xml code.

(Old) build.xml:

```
<target name="buildOsbProject">

        <java dir="${osb.home}/lib" jar="${eclipse.home}/plugins/${equinox.launcher.jar}" fork="true" failonerror="true" maxmemory="768m" >
            <jvmarg line="-XX:MaxPermSize=256m" />
            <arg line="-data ${workspace.dir}" />
            <arg line="-application com.bea.alsb.core.ConfigExport" />
            <arg line="-configProject OSBInboundServicesConfig" />
            <arg line="-configJar ${osbProject.configJar}" />
            <arg line="-configSubProjects OSBInboundServices" />
            <arg line="-includeDependencies true" />
            <arg line="--launcher.library plugins/${equinox.launcher.lib}" />
            <sysproperty key="weblogic.home" value="${weblogic.home}" />
            <sysproperty key="osb.home" value="${osb.home}" />
            <sysproperty key="osgi.bundlefile.limit" value="750" />
            <sysproperty key="harvester.home" value="${osb.home}/harvester" />
            <sysproperty key="osgi.nl" value="en_US" />
            <sysproperty key="sun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax" value="true" />
            <sysproperty key="middleware.home" value="${middleware.home}" />
            <sysproperty key="com.bea.plateng.common.util.logging.useJDKlogger" value="true"/>
            <sysproperty key="java.io.tmpdir" value="/tmp/salosb_tmp"/>
        </java>
    </target>
```

(New) build.xml

```
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${workspace.dir}/build/lib/ant-contrib.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <!--    Task Definition     -->
    <taskdef name="configjar" classname="com.bea.alsb.tools.configjar.ant.ConfigJarTask">
        <classpath>   
            <pathelement location="${osb.home}/tools/configjar/configjar.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <!-- This is the classpath for java runtime-->
    <path id="classpath.java">
        <fileset dir="lib">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="createSbConfigJar">
        <echo>OSB project config creation started</echo>
        <property name="settingsFileFull" value="${workspace.dir}/build/settings-file.xml"/>
        <property name="targetDirectory" value="${workspace.dir}/build"/>       
        <configjar debug="false" failonerror="true" errorProperty="" settingsFile="${settingsFileFull}"/>   
    </target>

<target name="buildDeployExportDelete" depends="clean,copylibs,createSbConfigJar,deleteFromOSB, prepareCustomization, importToOSB, setAuthorizationInformation,exportFromOSB">
        <antcall target="deleteFromOSB">
        </antcall>
    </target>
```

settings-file.xml

```
<configjarSettings xmlns="http://www.bea.com/alsb/tools/configjar/config">

    <source>
    <project dir="${workspace.dir}/OSBInboundServices"/>
    <system  dir="${workspace.dir}/OSBInboundServicesConfig"/>
  </source>

    <configjar jar="${workspace.dir}/sbconfig.jar" overwrite="true">
        <projectLevel includeSystem="true"/>
    </configjar>

</configjarSettings>
```

OSB_Env.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

export MW_HOME=/pkg/home/nonarch/Oracle/Middleware
export OSB_HOME=/pkg/home/nonarch/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_OSB1
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java6
export BEA_HOME=$MW_HOME
export WL_HOME=$MW_HOME/wlserver_10.3
export WLS_VER=10.3
export COMMON_COMPONENTS_HOME=$MW_HOME/oracle_common
export MODULES_DIR=$MW_HOME/modules

export PATH=$WL_HOME/server/bin:$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
export MEM_ARGS="-Xms32m -Xmx200m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"

export CONFIGJAR_HOME="$OSB_HOME/tools/configjar"
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dosb.home=$OSB_HOME -Dweblogic.home=$WL_HOME"
export JAVA_OPTIONS=" -Xverify:none"

CLASSPATH=$MW_HOME/modules/features/weblogic.server.modules_10.3.6.0.jar

CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$WL_HOME/server/lib/weblogic.jar
```

CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$MW_HOME/oracle_common/modules/oracle.http_client_11.1.1.jar:$MW_HOME/oracle_common/modules/oracle.xdk_11.1.0/xmlparserv2.jar:$MW_HOME/oracle_common/modules/oracle.webservices_11.1.1/orawsdl.jar:$MW_HOME/oracle_common/modules/oracle.wsm.common_11.1.1/wsm-dependencies.jar

CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$OSB_HOME/modules/features/osb.server.modules_11.1.1.7.jar:$OSB_HOME/soa/modules/oracle.soa.common.adapters_11.1.1/oracle.soa.common.adapters.jar:$OSB_HOME/lib/external/log4j_1.2.8.jar:$OSB_HOME/lib/alsb.jar

```
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$CONFIGJAR_HOME/configjar.jar:$CONFIGJAR_HOME/L10N

export CLASSPATH
```